# ASP.NET Core 2 System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I get this error when I try to perform migrations

> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined
>   for this object.    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)

What I am trying to do is use the Iconfiguration inside my dbcontext class. Is that possible to do? This is how I am currently doing it:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options,) : 
    base(options) { 
           Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: Configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:SchemaName"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9467), [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/639) and [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9415), probably one of them matches your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps below to achieve your requirement:

- Modify `AppDbContext`

  ```
   public class AppDbContext : DbContext
  {
       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
       public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IConfiguration configuration) : 
       base(options) { 
              Configuration = configuration;
      }
      public DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }


      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: Configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:SchemaName"]);
       }
       }
  ```
- From `Package Manager Console`, run `add-migration init`
- From `Package Manager Console`, run `update-database`